# What is the difference between running an application as a service or deploying it on a container?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, windows-services, archiva, web-container

I need to install the following applications for our continuous delivery strategy:

**Jenkins** and **Apache Archiva**

But they offer:

**to be install as a windows service** or
**to be deploy in a container** (i.e. Tomcat)

I was wondering if installing those applications as a service will give us better performance, reliability, security or whatsoever or the other way around or nothing at all

Thank you!

Comment: Are you  a developer and will the target computer in question be used for development?

Comment: I am a developer trainee and we are planning to adopt the continuous delivery strategy, basically we are going to have a build server for development. Thanks Tim

Comment: It depend on the scenario. For me since we try new plugins we have written a batch scrip which will start Jenkins without using tomcat or as a windows server.

Comment: @Anuja I can't see that will fit to our current state.. because we are just starting to learn continuous deployment and automation thing but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official documentation for installing Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins) on Windows:

> If you're running on Windows it is good to run Jenkins as a service so it starts up automatically without requiring a user to log in. The easiest way is to run the Windows installer, linked from Jenkins' homepage. This also has the advantage of being easier to automate.

If you deploy Jenkins to Tomcat, then every time you start up your computer you might have to manually start Tomcat.  In addition, if you want to stop or pause Jenkins running in a container you may have to manually shut down the container.  This can lead to problems if not done properly.

On other hand, if Jenkins be running as a service, then Windows will handle most of these things for you.  Unless you need to have very fine grain control over Jenkins I would leave it as a service.  One example where you *might* want to deploy it in Tomcat would be if you wrote a custom plugin and wanted to test it.